# PDO positional and named parameters as part of the same prepared query?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, prepared-statement

I'm learning the ropes with PDO.

Here is my sql (the number of parameters that can appear in the WHERE is variable).

```
    SELECT
        ID, title

    FROM
        table

    WHERE
        something = ?

    ORDER BY 
        :sort :dir 

    LIMIT 
        :start, :results
```

Here is my code:

```
        $query = $conn->prepare($sql);

        if ($parameters) {

            $i = 0;
            foreach ($parameters AS $parameter) {

                $i++;
                $query->bindParam($i, $parameter);

            }

        }

        $query->bindParam(':start', $pagination['start'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $query->bindParam(':results', $pagination['results'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $query->bindParam(':sort', $pagination['sort']);
        $query->bindParam(':dir', $pagination['dir']);

        $query->execute();
```

... and here is the exception that it generates:

```
 Invalid parameter number: mixed named and positional parameters
```

Is it impossible to combine positional and named parameters in the same query?  Or am I missing something?

Thanks!

Comment: I´m not sure about `LIMIT`, but `ORDER BY` does not accept parameters, at least not in the version of PHP that I am using (5.2.9)

Comment: MySQL won't accept *quoted values* for the `LIMIT` and `ORDER BY` clauses, which is what will happen when those placeholders are substituted.  It's not a PHP problem... and kind of makes your question moot.

Answer (score 12):

Yes, it's impossible.

[PDO.prepare](http://php.net/pdo.prepare)

You cannot use both named and question mark parameter markers within the same SQL statement; pick one or the other parameter style.

Comment: Ok thanks for the info.  Considering I have a variable number of parameters, is it then impossible to bind variables to the ORDER BY and LIMIT clauses?  (As I understand it, you can only do this with named parameters.  But named parameters do not lend themselves to situations with an unknown number of parameters.)

Comment: You can't bind column names, so you can't bind  :sort and :dir .  
Give names to all parameters.

Answer (score 2):

Use a wrapper function, a naive replacement function will suffice.

```
if (strpos($sql, ":")) {
    $i = -1;
    while (strpos($sql, "?") && isset($parameters[++$i])) {
        $parameters[":p$i"] = $parameters[$i];
        unset($parameters[$i]);
        $sql = preg_replace("/[?]/", ":p$i", $sql, 1);
    }
}
```

Mix `$sort` and `$dir` directly into the `$sql` query. These two are SQL identifiers, not data.